# Possible to display posts containing a short code ?

Tags: query-posts, shortcode

i have some posts with a certain shortcode in them. unfortunately these posts are in different categories and contain different tags so i am not able to query them. is it possible that i run a query which will display all posts containing this shortcode [fileurl=xx] where xx is a certain id (number).
Help is appreciated . 
cheers

Answer (score 1):

### Taxonomy Query

> Always use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for sidequeries. `query_posts()` is only for the Main query and `new WP_Query()` should be used for the second queries only. [Read more here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385).

You *can* query posts by a taxonomy (category, term, etc.):

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_janner',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'commedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
) );
```

### Shortcode Query

You could also, if you want to query by shortcode, add/remove a filter on the query for the content.

> Make *shure* that you read the comments **carefully**!

```
function wpse49871_shortcode_query_filter( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Lets be on the safe side, escape and such.
    $new_where = $wpdb->prepare( 
         "%s AND %s LIKE %s"
        ,$where
        ,"{$wpdb->posts}.post_content"
        // If you know the exact ID, then just insert it in here.
        ,like_escape( '%fileurl=%' )
    );

    return $new_where;
}
function wpse49871_get_shortcode_posts()
{
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_shortcode_query_filter' );
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        // Do your query in here. See "Taxonomy Query" args above for example
    ) );

    // Don't need it anymore after this run
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_shortcode_query_filter' );

    return $posts;
}
```

An [even better approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49549/how-to-get-posts-by-content/49556#49556) may be to wrap it up in a class like the one shown in the other Q.

Comment: Hiiz Thanks for the help Kaiser :} im getting an empty list out, please see here. http://www.designzzz.com/test-short.php also added the code i used in the text area on this page. please see if im doing something wrong! thanks

Comment: First: Set all the php error and WP DEBUG stuff to ON/true in your wp-config.php (search here on WPSE & in Codex & on php.net). Note: You have to have "` [fileurl=`" (leading space) - else it won't work.

Comment: turned it on plz check again : http://www.designzzz.com/test-short.php .. my god can't believe a single plugin creating so many errors..

Comment: That's not an error, just a `Notice`. There's a difference between `Notice/Warning/Error`. Btw: What`s `{filelink`? Shortcodes start with `[` square brackets... Plus: Why's the php function _inside a textarea_???

Comment: oh oh looks like i mistook it as a shortcode . did i ? its like this : {filelink=99} , {filelink=97} etc.... about the textarea i placed it to show you what code i am running. as in full

Comment: It's _not_ about a shortcode???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3207/discussion-between-ayaz-malik-and-kaiser)

Comment: I _am_ in chat.

Comment: so am i u getting my msgs ?

Comment: Why don't you come into chat? It's the link in the upper most menu ↑ named _chat_. Then go to "StopPress".