# How to add a list of all galleries to my sidebar?

Tags: gallery, sidebar

I'm using Wordpress 3.3.1 and trying to figure out how I can modify my sidebar to include a list of all the galleries. I see wp_get_posts and the like...but nothing for galleries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the [posts by content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49549/how-to-get-posts-by-content/49556#49556) for the string `'[gallery'`. You get an array of posts which you can list then in a widget or in plain PHP code.